# How to improve the spoken English?

Tags: vocabulary, pronunciation, spoken-english

How to improve the spoken English?
And I have little vocabulary.It makes me very distressed.I strongly hope that I can communicate with foreign friends in good English.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! This is rather a broad topic, but [Resources for learning English](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/735)/ has a lot of useful resources for you to try out.

Comment: What about taken a private teacher or a student of language, one lesson a week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to improve spoken skill you should speak a lot.

If you want to improve writing skill write a lot.

the same thing about reading and translating.

I have some links to help you.
1st is language exchange. If English is not your native you can "exchange" your native language to English. To speak to different people in your local language and improve your language. the link is http://www.sharedtalk.com/index.aspx

And another one is for accent
sometimes strong accent can make the speech not understandable
improve your accent with this website http://www.shiporsheep.com/

Have fun and good luck with your studying